# VS2019 equivalent of VS2015's vsvars32.bat

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, visual-studio-2019

we are on VS2015, but want to migrate on VS2019.
We have big build file, inside of it we build 17+ solutions. 
in the beginning of the build file there is

```
call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
```

it's targeting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools
```

if we open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools`
there is no any `vsvars32.bat`
so, what is an equivalent of this VS2015's file for VS2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“The VsDevCmd.bat file sets the appropriate environment variables to enable command-line builds.”

“ Note
Visual Studio 2015 and earlier versions used VSVARS32.bat, not VsDevCmd.bat for the same purpose.”

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-the-visual-studio-command-line.